# Not able to see Google Maps on Emulator

Tags: android

I try to work with android with goolge maps, using google Api 2.2 leve 8.

i generated the keystore and obtain the maos Api key

when i run the program i am getting a screen with google logo and screen with checks.

i also refered to the LOGCAT.

```
08-06 16:37:21.823: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(284): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
08-06 16:37:21.823: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(284): CheckJNI is ON
08-06 16:37:21.906: INFO/GTalkService(170): [ServiceAutoStarter] --- connectivity changed
08-06 16:37:21.906: INFO/GTalkService(170): [ServiceAutoStarter] --- start GTalk service ---
08-06 16:37:23.003: DEBUG/dalvikvm(66): GREF has increased to 301
08-06 16:37:23.073: DEBUG/GTalkService(170): [GTalkService.1] ### onCreate ###
08-06 16:37:23.483: INFO/ActivityManager(66): Start proc com.svox.pico for broadcast com.svox.pico/.VoiceDataInstallerReceiver: pid=293 uid=10010 gids={}
08-06 16:37:24.396: DEBUG/GTalkService(170): [GTalkService.1] setBackgroundDataWithLock: mBackgroundDataEnabled=true
08-06 16:37:24.923: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(284): --- registering native functions ---
08-06 16:37:25.383: INFO/ActivityThread(293): Publishing provider com.svox.pico.providers.SettingsProvider: com.svox.pico.providers.SettingsProvider
08-06 16:37:26.623: DEBUG/GTalkService(170): [GTalkService.1] onStartCommand: found 0 connections, force audit connections...
08-06 16:37:27.233: DEBUG/GoogleLoginService(170): onBind: Intent { act=android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator cmp=com.google.android.gsf/.loginservice.GoogleLoginService }
08-06 16:37:27.287: WARN/GoogleLoginService(170): Device has no accounts: sending Intent { act=com.google.android.gsf.LOGIN_ACCOUNTS_MISSING }
08-06 16:37:27.343: DEBUG/GTalkService(170): [GTalkService.19] account missing
08-06 16:37:27.483: DEBUG/GTalkService(170): [GTalkService.18] account missing
08-06 16:37:29.113: INFO/ActivityManager(66): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=cm.marakana.tutomaps/com.marakana.tutomaps.LocationActivity }
08-06 16:37:29.323: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(284): Shutting down VM
08-06 16:37:29.355: DEBUG/jdwp(284): adbd disconnected
08-06 16:37:29.425: INFO/AndroidRuntime(284): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
08-06 16:37:29.743: INFO/ActivityManager(66): Start proc cm.marakana.tutomaps for activity cm.marakana.tutomaps/com.marakana.tutomaps.LocationActivity: pid=308 uid=10041 gids={}
08-06 16:37:30.813: INFO/ActivityManager(66): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=cm.marakana.tutomaps/com.marakana.tutomaps.LocationActivity }
08-06 16:37:31.215: INFO/ARMAssembler(66): generated scanline__00000077:03545404_00000004_00000000 [ 47 ipp] (67 ins) at [0x2e8df8:0x2e8f04] in 20688664 ns
08-06 16:37:33.234: DEBUG/dalvikvm(308): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 4951 objects / 306736 bytes in 729ms
08-06 16:37:33.783: DEBUG/dalvikvm(308): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 9836 objects / 599792 bytes in 119ms
08-06 16:37:34.253: DEBUG/dalvikvm(308): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5037 objects / 328776 bytes in 104ms
08-06 16:37:34.775: DEBUG/dalvikvm(308): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 6209 objects / 378512 bytes in 115ms
08-06 16:37:35.363: DEBUG/dalvikvm(308): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 8541 objects / 651632 bytes in 119ms
08-06 16:37:35.853: DEBUG/dalvikvm(308): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 6078 objects / 370040 bytes in 115ms
08-06 16:37:36.513: INFO/MapActivity(308): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
08-06 16:37:36.562: ERROR/MapActivity(308): Couldn't get connection factory client
08-06 16:37:37.093: INFO/ActivityManager(66): Displayed activity cm.marakana.tutomaps/com.marakana.tutomaps.LocationActivity: 7534 ms (total 42545 ms)
08-06 16:37:42.403: DEBUG/dalvikvm(129): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1037 objects / 45704 bytes in 158ms
08-06 16:37:47.444: DEBUG/dalvikvm(170): GC_EXPLICIT freed 3704 objects / 422136 bytes in 199ms
08-06 16:37:47.903: DEBUG/dalvikvm(308): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 9852 objects / 735928 bytes in 164ms
```

I am unable find out the solution can any one having Idea

Answer (score 0):

Do you have these two lines in your Android Manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and in your  element:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Comment: yes . <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

Comment: Maybe provide code samples of how you're implementing it.  Are you extending MapActivity?

Comment: yes public class MarakanaMapsActivity extends MapActivity {
  
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }